# BCP Export Data convert

Tags: sql-server-bcp

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_helptext3] 
    (@ProcName VARCHAR(256))
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    DECLARE @path VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @filepath_loction VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @filepath_loction = '\\SOLVERLAPT292\tempfolder\new.txt'

    EXEC @path = sp_helptext2 @ProcName 

    SET @filepath_loction = @path
    SET @sql = 'bcp "' + @sql + '" queryout "' +  @filename +'" -c -r"''\n" 
-t"'',''" -S '+@@servername+' -T'

    SELECT @filepath_loction
END
```

Output I got it because not convert into text file format I get this error:

> Msg 214, Level 16, State 201, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
>   Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!